# Spring Data JPA: filter data based on used ManyToOne field

Tags: java, sql, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have an entity "Car" with "CarType" as @ManyToOne @joinColumn parameter:

Car entity:

```
@Entity
public class Car implements serializable {
  @Id
  private Long id;

  @ManyToOne(targetEntity = CarType.class)
  private CarType carType;

  ...
}
```

CarType entity:

```
@Entity
public class CarType implements serializable {
  @Id
  private Long id;
  private String name;
  private String version;
  
  ...
}
```

CarType repository:

```
@Repository
public interface CarType extends JpaRepository<CarType, Long> {
   List<CarType> findAllOrderByNameAsc();

}
```

Users ask for CarTypes, I have already an api that returns all carTypes, but some of them are no longer used (no existing car uses the carType)

is there any way to retrieve only "actual" used CarTypes using JpaRepository ?

Comment: How are you defining no longer used CarTypes in your code?

Comment: @dope no existing car uses the carType

Comment: You could retrieve the *distinct* carType from all cars in the database.

Comment: @ZakFST Did you find any solution yet?

Answer (score 2):

You have to write a custom query to get the actually used CarTypes data from the database.

```
@Query(
  value = "SELECT * FROM cartype t2 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM car as t1 WHERE t1.cartype = t2.id)", 
  nativeQuery = true)
List<CarTypes> findAllActiveCarTypes();
```